# Send parameter to another page

Tags: theming

I want to build a page that will be my player.
That page.tpl.php will include code like the following one:

```
<object bla bla ... idmedia="**the parameter that i want to get**"></object>.
```

I want to call this page with various parameters that play other videos.
I can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

you can your page with a GET variable appended in the url, something like

```
www.mysite.com/node/1?videoId=123
```

then inside your template you use a GET variable like this

```
$videoId = $_GET['VideoId'];
```

then you could do this

```
<object bla bla ... idmedia=" $videoId "></object>.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to have a block that provides links to other related content you would do it like this:

1. Create a content type to contain your player and whatever other information you want.
2. Add fields to contain any sorting categories that you want to use to relate the content such as subject categories, media author etc.  These fields can me created as Taxonomy fields which will provide the list of options you wish as input in the fields.
3. Create a View definition using the Views module to select the content type along with any other filtering or sorting criteria you want to apply to the main page for your media content.
4. Add a contextual filter to the view and apply it to a block so that the block will provide a list of the related content available for the contextual filter.

This sounds simple, but is not to someone new to Drupal.  There are excellent videos and other information on using Views at [Nodeone.se](http://dev.nodeone.se/en/taming-the-beast-learn-views-with-nodeone)